# How can I set a time variable that takes 2-months (bimonthly data)?

Tags: datetime, time, time-series, stata

I can't find a way to define a time variable in Stata that takes two months. I found in other forums the way to define intervals of 3 months (quarters) or to define it as a semester, but that is not what I'm looking for.

I have a data set like this

```
year month observation
2000   1        40
2000   2        10
2000   3        50
2000   4        10
```

I created a variable `bi_month` as

```
year month bi_month observation
2000   1       1        40
2000   2       1        10
2000   3       2        50
2000   4       2        10
```

but here I'm not able to use the following code nor the `tsset` command (because it doesn't have a command of definition bimonthly data)

```
 gen mdate = ym(year, bi_month)
 format mdate %tm
```

because Stata reads `bi_month` as indicating months from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bi-monthly (or bimonthly) doesn't seem to me especially transparent as a term. I recommend twice-monthly and two-monthly for two interpretations.

The main issue here is, it seems, wanting to work with an aggregation of monthly data to two-monthly data, specifically intervals Jan-Feb, ..., Nov-Dec. To that end I suggest representing two-month periods by the first month of each.

```
clear 
input year month whatever 
2000   1        40
2000   2        10
2000   3        50
2000   4        10
end 

gen mdate = ym(year, month) 

gen m2date = 2 * floor(mdate/2) 

format m*date %tm 

list


     +-------------------------------------------+
     | year   month   whatever    mdate   m2date |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2000       1         40   2000m1   2000m1 |
  2. | 2000       2         10   2000m2   2000m1 |
  3. | 2000       3         50   2000m3   2000m3 |
  4. | 2000       4         10   2000m4   2000m3 |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

Now such data can't be `tsset` or `xtset` using the new two-monthly date because each such date doesn't occur uniquely in the dataset.

But supposing that you reduce your dataset so that each two-monthly date occurs just once (or, maximally, once per panel). Now `tsset` or `xtset` is within reach, and the needed twist is just to set `delta(2)`.

```
    collapse whatever, by(year m2date) 

    tsset m2date, delta(2) 

    list 

    +--------------------------+
     | year   m2date   whatever |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | 2000   2000m1         25 |
  2. | 2000   2000m3         30 |
     +--------------------------+
```

Representing each two-month period by the second month of each is equally systematic.  Just add 1 to the recipe for `m2date` above.

Note: Strictly `xtset` requires only a panel identifier and doesn't insist on times occurring at most once for each panel. I am not sure that is widely useful, but it's another story.

Comment: thanks, this is a good solution! to bad there isn't twice-monthly interpretation by Stata

Comment: You could add minute, hour, am/pm, two-weekly, four-monthly, biennial, quadrennial, ... as time units Stata does not support directly, but what are you missing really? With an extra command or two,  defining your own time basis is not difficult.